# Can't read 'null' of length property despite catching for it

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which fetches data from a database, and while it's doing this displays a 'loading' spinner. This is done in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {

        axios.post("/api/fetch/fetchEducation", {
            id: props.id
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            setEducation(response.data)
        })
        .then(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
    }, [props.id])
```

It sets the state of an array, declared like this:

```
const [education, setEducation] = useState([])
```

In the return of the component, I'm trying to..

1. Check if education (state) has any data, and if loading is false.
2. If education is null, or has no length, then display an empty dashboard.
3. If education has a length that isn't 0, or isn't null, then display the dashboard.

At the moment, the endpoint is returning 'null' in data, if the data doesn't exist.

The component looks like this:

```
<div className="dashboard-parent">
            <div className="dashboard">
                { loading === true ? <DashboardPending /> : null }
                { (education == null || education.length === 0) && loading === false ? <EmptyDashboard content="No education added." /> : null }
                { ( education != null || education.length > 0) && loading === false ? 
                <>
                { education.map((edu, index) => {
                    return (
                        <DashboardListItem first={edu.Course} second={edu.Institution} third={edu.StartDate} fourth={edu.EndDate} key={index} />
                    )
                })}
                </> : null }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Unfortunately,

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: can you try putting check like  setEducation(response.data ?? []) and  education?.map(

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because your are getting null from the api's response and setting the education state as also null. After that in the function return, you are trying to get the length of the null.

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [education, setEducation] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {

        axios.post("/api/fetch/fetchEducation", {
            id: props.id
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            setEducation(response.data)
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
    }, [props.id])
    
    
 return (
      <div className="dashboard-parent">
        <div className="dashboard">
          {
            loading ? <DashboardPending /> : 
              (
                education !== null ? (
                  education.map((edu, index) => {
                    return (
                        <DashboardListItem first={edu.Course}                             second={edu.Institution} third=                                  {edu.StartDate} fourth={edu.EndDate} key=                           {index} />
                    )
                })
                ) : <EmptyDashboard content="No education added."                   />
              )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
 )
```

Comment: To improve this answer, I'd suggest also to check for `education.length`, cause it might be not null, but empty array, so you would want to display EmptyDashboard component